# Every positive polynomial is above a completely Q-factorized positive polynomial?

Tags: real-analysis, polynomials

Let $P$ be a unitary polynomial with rational coefficients in one variable $x$, such that $P(x) \geq 0$ for all $x \in \mathbb R$. Then $P$ is of even degree, say $2d$. Is it true that there always exist $d$ rational numbers $q_1,q_2, \ldots ,q_d$ such that

$$
P(x) \geq \bigg( \prod_{k=1}^{d} (x-q_k)^2\bigg),
$$

for all $x\in \mathbb R$ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. It's not even true for $d=1$: $(x-\sqrt{2})^2$ is a counterexample.

Comment: Oops. I had mistakenly put "real coefficients" instead of "rational coefficients" in the OP ; it's corrected now. Note that this new question is always true for d=1 (this is what the canonical form is all about).